# Django admin - Limit the choices in dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am starting to use Django and I have an issue trying to filter data based on user information. Let me explain how my app works. A `User` in my app belongs to a company. So I created a table called `Company` to capture company info. Then I created another table called `UserCompany`. Basically, it stores the `Id` from the Django `User` and the `Id` from my company table. Now, I want to filter data so that the user will see results filtered in the Django Admin based on their company id. He/She can only see data based on their company `Id`. I was able to figure this user out using `get_queryset` in admin.py. My only issue now is, the dropdown list that shows in admin as a result of foreign keys isn't being filtered. I did some research and found out about `limit_choices_to`. I can set that statically like this:

```
class Cleaner(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company',limit_choices_to = {'companyname' = 'Test'}
```

The dropdown list in the admin section only shows the company Test. How can I do this dynamically? Do I do it in the model or do I do it in admin.py? Please help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's time to setup CustomAdmin for your models now. You will have to override formfield_for_foreignkey method of ModelAdmin

```
class CleanerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
         if db_field.name == "company":
                 kwargs["queryset"] = Company.objects.filter(name='Test')
         return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Cleaner, CleanerAdmin)
```

If there are session specific filter for which you need reference to logged in user object you also have reference to request object. You can write any logic here.

Comment: You could use `kwargs['queryset'] = db_field.related_model.objects.filter(name='Test')` to do not use hardcoded model

Comment: Thanks, I have been struggling to get this done. this helped a lot

Answer (score -1):

```
@admin.register(Cleaner)
class CleanerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
         if db_field.name == "company":
                 kwargs["queryset"] = db_field.related_model.objects.filter(name='Test')
         return super(CleanerAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This answer should have some text explaining the code.