# Django admin filter tabularInline field choices based on modelAdmin field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880634/django-admin-limit-the-choices-in-dropdown) post to limit the choices in my related "tabularInline" field.

```py
class inlineUsages(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Usage 
    extra = 0
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        print(db_field.name)
        print(kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "project":
             kwargs["queryset"] = Project.objects.filter(task='Project 3')
        return super(inlineUsages, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

class fteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (inlineUsages,)
admin.site.register(FTE, fteAdmin)
```

Both the FTE model and Usage model reference a foreign key "project" on the "Project" model. My filtering is correctly working, but currently (as you see in the code) I can only hard code the Project name (field is called "task"). I want to be able to filter the choices of my Usage project field based on the value of the FTE project field. I am not sure how to pass the relation between models. Any help is appreciated! Below is the current view in the django admin portal[image]